# Windows: Changing the name/icon of an application associated with a file type

Tags: windows, registry, file-association

I would like to associate a file type in Windows with a particular application, but I need to make it so when the user opens the "Open With" menu, the name and icon of the application in the list is customized for that file type (i.e., not simply the name and icon of the executable).

This is because the binary is a general binary that runs many different apps, depending on its command-line arguments (similar to`python.exe` or `javaws.exe`). I don't want the "Open With" menu to show "Python" or "Java", I want it to show the name and icon for the application that is being passed on the command-line.

I know how to add file associations (by creating a [ProgID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144152%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`, and adding the ProgID name to either [OpenWithProgids](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh127445%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts`](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/630ed1d9-73f1-4cc0-bc84-04f29cffc13b)), but I cannot find any way to change the name or icon of the application as it appears in the "Open With" menu for files of that type. Is this possible?

(**Edited** to clarify my existing understanding of adding file associations.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a partial solution which allows the name to be set (but not the icon or company name).

It is possible to [register an application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee872121%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in Windows. This is very similar to creating a [ProgID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144152%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but it allows you to set the **FriendlyAppName**. For some reason, you can't set the FriendlyAppName on a ProgID.
Unfortunately, **FriendlyAppName** is not a string, but a reference to a resource in a .DLL or .EXE file. Go figure.

So:

- Create a dummy .dll file for the virtual application with which you want to associate the file. It doesn't have to have any code in it, just resources. Give it a string resource containing the title of the application.
- Create a key `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\whatever.exe` (whatever should be a unique name specific to the virtual application -- it *does not* need to be the name of a real executable, but it *does* need to end in `.exe` or another executable extension).

  - Set the default value, **DefaultIcon** and **shell**, as described in [Programmatic Identifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144152%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). This sets the name and icon for the file type when this association is the default, as well as the shell command to run.
  - Also give it a **FriendlyAppName** value referring to the dummy .dll. For example, if your app name string is string number 23, set **FriendlyAppName** to "@PATH\TO\DLL.dll,-23".
  - Add a **SupportedTypes** key and add a value for each type that the virtual application can handle.

Now the application will appear in the "Other Programs" dropdown of the "Choose default program" dialog, but not in the "Open With" menu. To properly associate it, you need to:

- Go to the file extension's entry in the registry. This should be in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts` (it can also be in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`, but I have found that the `FileExts` version overrides, and Windows creates one there if the user manually creates a file association, so best to use that one).

  - Under **OpenWithList**, there needs to be an entry for the fake `whatever.exe` you created above. This should be a value whose name is an arbitrary letter and whose value is the fake exe name.
  - Also under **OpenWithList**, you *need* to ensure that the `MRUList` value includes the letter you assigned to the fake executable in the previous step.
  - I don't *believe* you need to add it to **OpenWithProgids** (it works without this), but the documentation tells you to.
  - To make it the default handler, under **UserChoice**, set **Progid** to "`Applications\whatever.exe`". This is optional, but there *needs* to be something set here (if **UserChoice** is missing, nothing will work).

Lastly, hit it with a [SHChangeNotify](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762118%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to refresh Windows' icon and shortcut cache. (I'm not sure if this is necessary after all; I just noticed that it helps to make Windows notice the changes you're making.)

Now on the "Open With" menu for the file type, you should see an entry for the custom string you put in the dummy .dll. It will still have the icon of the real binary mentioned in the shell command, but you can at least control the name. Why, why is this so hard?

I will leave this question open for awhile in case there are better answers.

Answer (score 0):

It's slightly complicated, but basically you need to [create a ProgID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165967%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to refer to the application itself, then add a [OpenWithProgIDs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166549%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) key to the extension.

More detail on setting up a ProgID [is here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144152%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: That only helps me with creating a new file type association. As far as I can tell from [that documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144152%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), you can set the *icon* (**DefaultIcon**) and *name* (default value) of the file type itself, but there is no field for setting either the *icon* or *name* of the application as seen in the "Open With" menu. Is there anything I can set in the ProgID that will change the way it looks in the Open With menu?

Comment: You should be able to create a completely new ProgID that's not referenced anywhere else and then just reference it from the OpenWithProgIDs key.

Comment: But there is nothing in the ProgID that lets me set the name or icon of the application in the Open With menu. It will always be "Python" (in the Python example), but I want to be able to dynamically set it to the name of the Python app.