# Get Associated Filetype Icon for a File

Tags: python, file, icons, file-type

## What I Want

I'm trying to write a function which takes in a filename and returns the icon of the application that is associated with the file's filetype on my system (which is Windows 7).

## What I've Tried

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10990092/how-to-find-via-python-the-icon-associated-with-a-windows-file), but the answer isn't giving me the details I need. I'm not very familiar with the ctypes module and I find the docs on the VC++ functions difficult to follow.

I also saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16829736/windows-changing-the-name-icon-of-an-application-associated-with-a-file-type), but I get stuck on the first hurdle.
When I try:

```
import _winreg
_winreg.OpenKey(_winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, 'Software\Microsoft\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts')
```

It raises a `WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified`

Even when I do

```
_winreg.OpenKey(_winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, 'Software\Microsoft')
```

Which returns a `PyHKEY object`, any 'key' action I try perform on it raises a `TypeError: The object is not a PyHKEY object`

Comment: Strings literals containing backslashes need to either double them all, or have `r` (raw-string) prefix. i.e. `'Software\\Microsoft'` or `r'Software\Microsoft'`.

Comment: What does "isn't giving me the details I need" mean?

Comment: @martineau good point but in this case the slashes are automatically escaped, r'' made no difference.

Comment: @abarnert mainly how to use the ExtractIconA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found an answer [here](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-win32/2009-May/009092.html)

the code from the link is:

```
import win32ui
import win32gui
import win32con
import win32api
import cStringIO
import Image

tempDirectory = os.getenv("temp")
ico_x = win32api.GetSystemMetrics(win32con.SM_CXICON)

dst = cStringIO.StringIO()

large, small = win32gui.ExtractIconEx(path,0)
win32gui.DestroyIcon(small[0])

#creating a destination memory DC
hdc = win32ui.CreateDCFromHandle( win32gui.GetDC(0) )
hbmp = win32ui.CreateBitmap()
hbmp.CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, ico_x, ico_x)
hdc = hdc.CreateCompatibleDC()

hdc.SelectObject( hbmp )

#draw a icon in it
hdc.DrawIcon( (0,0), large[0] )
win32gui.DestroyIcon(large[0])

#convert picture
hbmp.SaveBitmapFile( hdc, tempDirectory + "\Icontemp.bmp")

im = Image.open(tempDirectory + "\Icontemp.bmp")
im.save(dst, "JPEG")

dst.seek(0)

os.remove(tempDirectory + "\Icontemp.bmp")    
return dst.read()
```

Comment: I am interested in the very same problem solved by my predecessors in a super hacky way. Unfortunately your solution does not even compile - path is undefined (as is win32ui), Image is not a standard import etc. Please correct it and add some comments on what you are doing and I will upvote

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D it works for me.  Perhaps fix whatever is wrong on your end before down voting?

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D He wasn't too far off, check out my answer if you still need this.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some working py2 code for you. Unfortunately I definitely do NOT understand everything going on here, but I can at least say that it definitely does work!

```
import win32ui
import win32gui
import win32con
import win32api


def save_icon(exe_file, out_file):
    ico_x = win32api.GetSystemMetrics(win32con.SM_CXICON)
    ico_y = win32api.GetSystemMetrics(win32con.SM_CYICON)

    large, small = win32gui.ExtractIconEx(exe_file, 0)
    win32gui.DestroyIcon(large[0])

    hdc = win32ui.CreateDCFromHandle(win32gui.GetDC(0))
    hbmp = win32ui.CreateBitmap()
    hbmp.CreateCompatibleBitmap( hdc, ico_x, ico_y )
    hdc = hdc.CreateCompatibleDC()

    hdc.SelectObject( hbmp )
    hdc.DrawIcon( (0,0), small[0] )
    hbmp.SaveBitmapFile( hdc, out_file )
```

Comment: This gives me ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    save_icon(r"C:\Users\jakub\Desktop\GitHub Desktop.lnk", "out")
  File "C:\Users\jakub\Desktop\python\grab_icon.py", line 12, in save_icon
    win32gui.DestroyIcon(large[0])
IndexError: list index out of range```