# get system icon for any file type as a image

Tags: python, tkinter

so, for my current program i need to get the system icon(or any identifying icon for the file type)
of a file type, example ('png' -> icon for png) and the output needs to be insertable into a tkinter object. im using windows too.

so first i tryed the reply's to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25511706/get-associated-filetype-icon-for-a-file) post, then [this](https://programtalk.com/python-examples/win32gui.ExtractIconEx/#google_vignette) one. but all the code returned nothing and was hard to read, i also assumed i could take the bitmaps they spat out and load that into pillow if that helps.

also sorry if this post was poorly made, i have not really use stack overflow before

Comment: You can do a google search on "png image icon" and find lots of examples.  So use one of those.  What is the difficulty?

Comment: the difficulty is i need it to be automated, and in more file types then just png, sorry if i was not clear but that was just a example, it could be any file type under the sun.

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts to this: finding which icon it is, and loading the icon.  Dakota has written a correct answer that shows how to use SHGetFileInfo to get the icon, but it has been deleted.  I hope they undelete the answer, because it is the right way.

Here's how to do it The Hard Way.  All File Manager icons have to be stored as resources in some executable (or DLL).  The icon identifier is stored in the registry.  If you go to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.png`, the default value for that key contains `pngfile`.  That's a generic identifier that might be used by several related extensions.

If you then go to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\pngfile`, in the `FriendlyTypeName` value, you'll find a string like `@%SystemRoot%\System32\shell32.dll,-30598`.

That tells you that the icon for pngfile files is stored in `shell32.dll`, as an ICON resource with identifier -30598 (which, since this is a 16-bit field, is 34938 or 0x887A).

You can then use the resource APIs to pull that resource from the resources of that particular DLL.

Comment: thanks so much to the detailed reply, what 'resource APIs' are you referring too? looking around trying to figure out how to extract the resources has gotten me no where. your help is appreciated